# Update table column based on another table values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sum

Let's say I have 2 tables:

First one is **products**:

```
+------------------+-----------------+--------+
| Product Name     |      Type       | Price  |
+------------------+-----------------+--------+
| Carrots          | Vegetables      | 10     |
| Oranges          | Fruits          |     20 |
| Beer             | Drinks          |     50 |
| Milk             |  Dairy products |     30 |
| Burgers          |  meat           |     40 |
| Baguettes        | bread           |    10  |
```

Second one is **Combos**:

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
| Item1     |  Item2  |   Item3   |  TotalPrice |
+-----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
| Carrots   | Oranges | Beer      |             |
| Milk      | Burgers | Baguettes |             |
+-----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

I want to update the  total price of each combo based on the sum price of its products.

For example, The 'TotalPrice' column of the Milk, Burgers and Baguettes combo would be 80.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to calculate the sum based on the combo's items:

```
UPDATE combos SET total_price = (SELECT SUM(price) FROM products
    WHERE product_name IN (item1, item2, item3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not quite right, the relation is not correctly represented. Think about two entities `Product` and `Combo`, and about how are they related. One `Combo` can certainly have many `Product`, right? But also, a `Product` can belong to many `Combo`, agree? So it means that the relation between the two is `many-to-many`. To model this relationship you need a third table, `Combo_Product` which will contain a record only if a `Product` belongs to a `Combo`.

With this model, you can simply join the two with the brige table and perform the aggregation to obtain any sum.

The query would be in the lines of:

```
select c.id_combo, sum(p.price)
from combo c
join combo_product cp on c.id_combo = cp.id_combo
join product p on cp.id_product = p.id_product
group by c.id_combo;
```